# Proving that powerset is a power object in category of sets and functions

Tags: category-theory

I've been trying to prove that powerset is a power object in the category $\mathbf{Set}$. (using an isomorphism $\mathcal{P}X \to 2^X$, mapping each subset  to its characteristic function).

I got to the point where I've proven that, form the definition (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+object), if we take the morphism $\chi_r (d):c \to 2$, such that $\chi_r (y) (x) = 1 \text{ iff } (x,y) \in r$ (for all $x \in c, y \in d$). Then I've shown that for every other $r'$, for which the digram commutes, and that there is a unique morphism $r' \to r$. What remains is to show that $\chi_R$ is the unique such morphism, so we assume there is another, different function $\chi$, for which the diagram commutes (and try to get a contradiction). I've split it in 2 cases:

1. There is $(x_0,y_0) \in r$ such that $\chi(y_0) (x_0) = 0$, for some $x_0 \in c$ and $y_0 \in d$
2. There is $(x_0,y_0) \notin r$ such that $\chi(y_0) (x_0) = 1$, for some $x_0 \in c$ and $y_0 \in d$

The first case, I've shown that the diagram doesn't commute, so we got a contradiction. However, the second case, I can't do. I've tried to assume that there is a $r'$ with morphisms to $c \times d$ and $\in_c$ such that diagram commutes and I've tried to find 2 morphisms $r' \to r$, which are not unique up to composition with an isomorphism (so we wouldn't have a pullback), but I failed to do so. I've also tried to show that the diagram can't commute, but I was unable to do it either.

Comment: It might be easier to prove a lemma about this general situation: if $f : X \to Z$ and $g : Y \to Z$ with $g$ monic, then the pullback of $f$ and $g$ is isomorphic to $\{ x\in X \mid \exists y\in Y, g(y) = f(x) \} = \{ x\in X \mid f(x) \in \operatorname{im}(g) \}$, with the map to $X$ being inclusion and the map to $Y$ being the restriction of $f$.  Then, show that with your definition of $\chi_r$, the pullback of $(\operatorname{id}, \chi_r)$ and ${\in}_X \hookrightarrow X \times 2^X$ gives exactly the desired subset of $X\times d$ according to that formula.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I've tried using the lemma, it shortens the proof, but I'm still stuck in the same place. I'm trying to prove that if we take another function $\chi$, as in case 2. of the OP, we shouldn't get a set which is isomorphic to $r$. WLOG we can assume that the pullback of the diagram containing $\chi$, $y$ is proper superset $r \subsetneqq y$ (otherwise we can use the first case). Now, if both of $r$ and $y$ are infinite (and the same cardinality), there can be a bijection between them. How do I exclude that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my convenience, I am going to do the problem with the slightly different construction that the required power object of $c$ is $\mathcal{P} c$, the set of subsets of $c$; and ${\in}_c := \{ (x, S) \in c \times \mathcal{P} c \mid x \in S \}$ with the map to $c \times \mathcal{P} c$ being the inclusion map.  Hopefully, it should be straightforward to translate this proof to your construction of the power object being ${}^c 2$.

Now, to show the uniqueness of the function $\chi_r$: first, suppose we have $(x, y) \in c \times d$ is in the image of $r \to c\times d$.  Then the commutative diagram gives that $(x, \chi_r(y)) \in {\in}_c$, so $x \in \chi_r(y)$.  Conversely, suppose $x\in \chi_r(y)$.  Then we have a map $\{ * \} \to c \times d, * \mapsto (x, y)$ and a map $\{ * \} \to {\in}_c, * \mapsto (x, \chi_r(y))$ which have compatible compositions $\{ * \} \to c \times \mathcal{P}c, * \mapsto (x, \chi_r(y))$.  Since $r$ is a pullback of the two maps, there exists a function $\{ * \} \to r$ such that the composition with $r\to c\times d$ is $* \mapsto (x, y)$.  This implies that $(x, y)$ is in the image of $r \to c\times d$.

We have thus shown that for every $x\in c, y\in d$, we have $x\in \chi_r(y)$ if and only if $(x, y)$ is in the image of $r\to c\times d$.  Therefore, in fact we must have $\chi_r(y) = \{ x \in X \mid (x, y) \in \operatorname{im}(r\to c\times d) \}$ for all $y\in d$, which pins down $\chi_r$ to only one possibility.

Comment: So in terms of the situation you were asking about, if $(x_0, y_0)\notin r$ and $\chi(y_0)(x_0) = 1$, then the required diagram is not a pullback square.

Comment: I've come up with a different way to prove it earlier. I just applied your comment to the function from the 2nd case (constructed another pullback $r'$ in the same manner, but with different function $\chi$) and now it's sufficient to prove that $r \ncong r'$. But the same argument as the first case in the OP can be used. If they were isomorphic, $r$ would be the pullback of the new diagram, but the diagram with $r$ as a pullback doesn't commute. This proof, however, seems more elegant. Thank you for your help.